# Complement of Closed Interval with Closed Subset

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I have a basic topology question. Let's say I have some interval $[a,b] \subset \mathbb{R}$ and $K \subset [a,b]$, with $K$ closed and having positive measure (this is not entirely relevant). Is it true that $U = [a,b] \setminus K$ is open in the topology on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: No. Take $K = \{(a+b)/2\}$. So $[a,b]/K = [a,\frac{a+b}{2}) \cup (\frac{a+b}{2},b]$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take for example $[\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4}] \subseteq [0,1]$.  Now, $[0,1]
 \setminus [\frac{1}{2},\frac{3}{4}]$ has no open balls around zero contained in the set.